# custom behaviour across controls - use a custom control, or user control with one child

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, custom-controls

In the system I'm working on we have a lot of grids, with very repetitive behaviours and properties. I'm going to make refactor and separate those to one common control that can be used in the whole system.

But I have a doubt - use CustomControll to achieve this, or UserControl?

- Custom Control - I do not need to overwrite OnPaint at all, so it's a bit overkill. But on other hands - this control will be indeed a special case of Grid control, so inheritance seems to be natural chose.
- User Control - it seems to fit better to make "some system control with preset properties and behaviors", but it will be containing only one child - the grid control. No composition. So it seems that using user control here is not what creation of User control mechanism had in mind

So what You guys think? It's better to use CustomControl, UserControl, or just throw programming away and became a monk?